# Status Bar then ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, statusbar, viewdidload

My App is a classic tab bar Application.
When one of the view controllers of the Tab Bar is already loaded when i receive a call, the the windows scrolls down perfectly, and up again at the end of the call.
If, while in a call ( the status bar is present ) the user selects a tab bar Item that was never selected before then the associated view controller is loaded, but the images are totally off.

In the viewDidLoad methods, i programmatically place images at absolute coordinates and also define the size for each object. If i add a Y offset (20 points of the Status bar), the object are still off.

It is very interesting to note that the offset is not constant (images at the top of the screen and really off than those at the bottom are a little less... ( i would understand, may be, a constant misalignment, but i have no idea what's going on here) ...

The use auto layout is checked, but i have not enter any constraints and place the object programmatically ( i.e. not with storyboard )

I have simple constant and C arrays where i store the coordinates and size for my images.

Here is the code in ViewDidload

```
for (int i =0; i< 16; i++ ){
  [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord[i],yCoord[i],buttonSize,buttonSize)];
  UIImage *img= [UIImage imageNamed: [ KP_BW objectAtIndex: KP_BW_Index]] ; 

  [imgView setImage:img]; 
  [self.view addSubview:imgView];
}
```

Comment: Try putting that in viewDidAppear and see if you see the same thing. Even though view loads in viewDidLoad, but actual screen size and all that is generally available after one of viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear

Comment: Thank you for the repsonse. However, if i do that am i not creating all the 16 subviews all over again, each time the view appears ?

Comment: Yeah you can put in a check, I think viewDidLoad is not a very good place for setting up views based on coordinates. Because, at that point we don't get lot of data such as frame, orientation etc.

Comment: Thanks again. I put the check point and created all the view in vieWill Appear but got the same "punition". I realized some subviews are having their height compressed for some reasons so my round images become oblong images.

Comment: That's strange, give one more try :) on viewDidAppear and also disable auto layout just for testing.

Comment: AutoLayout unset and ViewDidAppear did not change anything unfortunately